# Android: Game has black bar on the side (In screenshot only)

Tags: java, android

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGXfE.jpg
I'm dealing with Screen size issues.

This black bar was not there when I was using my old phone (galaxy S7). But on my new one (Poco F3, 2400x1080p) there is this black bar.

It is not visible in-game! Only on the screenshot, which I found pretty weird. The big problem is that now the UI that is on the right is halfway offscreen and won't come out fully.

I tried display.getRealSize(screenSize); it gives correct 1080x2400p res. If I try display.getHeight (deprecated), I get an odd smaller value and I have no idea where the phone gets that. By using that, the game is still fullscreen, but the right-side UI comes out TOO far as opposed to too little.

I guess my question is this: What's the best place to define screen size? Is there a way to get rid of that black bar? Do I have to disable some sort of invisible bottom bar of the phone? Or is the screen just actually smaller than it is in Pixels? Man, this is sort of frustrating to deal with.

```
public void setScreenSize(Context context) {
    int x, y, orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    WindowManager wm = ((WindowManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Point screenSize = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            display.getRealSize(screenSize);
            x = screenSize.x;
            y = screenSize.y;
        } else {
            display.getSize(screenSize);
            x = screenSize.x;
            y = screenSize.y;
        }
    } else {
        x = display.getWidth();
        y = display.getHeight();
    }
  
     screenwidth = x;
     screenheight = y;
     Point screenSize = new Point();
     display.getRealSize(screenSize);

     screenheight=screenSize.y;
     screenwidth=screenSize.x;

    Log.d("screensize", "w "+screenwidth);
    Log.d("screensize", "h "+screenheight);
}
```

Thanks to anyone who took their time to read this! If you have any ideas or dealt with this issue before, let me know, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

This solved it. It was the top "notch" aka the phone camera dot cutout